# tailwind negative value with prefix class

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

in my `tailwind.config.js` I've setup this

```
module.exports = {
  prefix: "tw-",
}
```

then I tried `class="tw--top-4"` but `top: '-4px'` is not reflected. I read the doc the negative value can be class="-top-4" but what about you want to use it with prefix? I also tried `class="-tw-top-4"` but no luck.

Comment: Well `top-4` would correspond to `1rem` which would not be `4px` unless you have set the document default font size to 4 pixels. By "no luck" when you set `tw-top-4` do you get top set to anything at all? And are you using React with JSX? If so, you should use `className="..."` not `class="..."`! You may be able to set absolute pixels with `tw-top-[4px]` however I'd get the basics working first.

Answer (score 2):

The working variant right now is `tw--top-4` (but for some reason autocomplete shows `-tw-top-4` instead, it's probably a bug), so negation comes after the prefix. There is a discussion about it on Github, but right it is like that.

To actually apply it you also need to add position for the element, e.g. `relative` or an `absolute` and etc. (don't forget your prefix too)

Example:

```
<div class="tw-text-red-500 tw-relative tw--bottom-4">
  One
</div>
<div class="tw-text-green-500">
  Two
</div>
<div class="tw-text-blue-500">
  Three
</div>
```

[Playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/zypvTUxU65)